# How does the bluetooth a2dp profile work?

Tags: android, bluetooth, audio-streaming, a2dp

I want to create a bluetooth music player application which streams audio from one device to another. I have read everything on the android developers page about [bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) and I found that a profile called a2dp has been specifically created for audio streaming. However not much has been provided on how to use it. I have also gone through the [bluetooth chat example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat) but i have been unable to figure out how to actually send audio and how to receive it. I have also read that a2dp sink functionality has been added as of android 5.0.
After spending hours on stackoverflow I see numerous questions asking the same thing but without any satisfactory answer.

My main questions are-

1. How does the bluetooth a2dp profile work?
2. Are there better methods to implement audio streaming between
   android devices apart from a2dp?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [AVDTP core specification](https://ecfsapi.fcc.gov/file/6516485297.pdf) to know what happens during an a2dp connection.
But if you want to know about the working of it in terms of coding, I suggest you go through [this](http://strayinsights.blogspot.com/2018/05/android-audio-tutorial-part-one.html) blog which I found useful.